# get site-packages folder from a python unittest

Tags: python, package

I have a standard python **proj** package::

```
proj/
├── proj
│   ├── data
│   │   └── data.csv
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── lib.py
├── MANIFEST.in
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── lib_test.py
```

`data/data.csv` is installed with *MANIFEST.in* and *include_package_data* key in setup.py::

```
~/proj$ more setup.py
 from setuptools import setup
 setup(name='proj',
       version=1.0,
       packages=['proj'],
       test_suite = 'tests',
       include_package_data=True,
       zip_safe=False)

~/proj$ more MANIFEST.in
include proj/data/*.csv
```

So after a `python setup.py install` data.csv is in the place I want in site-packages::

```
$ tree ~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/proj-1.0-py2.7.egg
~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/proj-1.0-py2.7.egg
├── EGG-INFO
│   └── ...
└── proj
    ├── data
    │   └── data.csv
    ├── __init__.py
    └── ...
```

In setup.py, *test_suite* is declared, so when I call test from `proj` first
folder, this work well::

```
~/proj$ python setup.py test
running test
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
OK
```

I would like to use in my unitest the `data.csv` file from: ~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/proj-1.0-py2.7.egg/proj/data/data.csv.
In short a way to get **~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/proj-1.0-py2.7.egg/proj/data/** folder.

With this code::

```
$ more tests/lib_test.py
import unittest, os, proj
from proj.lib import get_data
class TestUtils(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_data(self):
        datapath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(proj.__file__)) + '/data'
        data = '{}/data.csv'.format(datapath)
        print '\n my data:', data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Using `__file__` I only succed to get **~/sandbox/proj/proj/data/data.csv**::

```
$ python setup.py test
running test
...
test_get_data (tests.lib_test.TestUtils) ...
 my data: ~/sandbox/proj/proj/data/data.csv
ok
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

Comment: So you want your local development version to use unittests from whatever the system-level installed package has? That seems like a bad idea for a few reasons, can you elaborate some more on why you want/need to do this?

Comment: unittest are not the only ones that need this data, I need this data.csv from scripts that will be run on production after we deploy this proj with a wheel.

Comment: Are those scripts part of proj? If so, don't they get installed with it and so would use the installed data file? Your question is specifically asking about unit tests, and you haven't actually answered my question about why you need to do this.

Comment: In other terms, I've succeed to deploy some data packaged with the code (in site-package) so I would like to ge able to get it from my python code, my unittest python code is one of the use case.

Comment: Are you saying that data.csv doesn't actually exist as part of the source ?repo? for proj? Because your question makes it look like it is. Or you're saying the data in production is different from the data in your source repo?

Comment: The above code snippet expose clearly that data.csv is part of the code, and is packaged with it, that's why data.csv is in site-packages/proj-1.0-py2.7.egg/proj/data/ folder on production after a "python setup.py install". So I need to access from python code to the data.csv, in production.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101826/discussion-between-tom-dalton-and-user3313834).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact

```
python setup.py test
```

does not load python package from the place `python setup install` put it (~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/proj-xxx), but from the place the `python setup.py test` is run.

That's why with:

```
import proj, os
os.path.abspath(proj.__file__)
```

we can't catch the `site-package` folder but only the working-copy files.